# Accounting to reflect the balance due

Tags: excel, excel-formula, accounting

[image: Rent Ledger]

In the above example, I am trying to determine the balance due for a tenant who makes partial payments every month.  As you can see, Column `I` reflects what should be the balance and the first row is correct.  However, the second row is not correct because it does not consider row 1's balance.

I want the balance due reflected for this one tenant *and also keep track of other tenants in the same log*.  If this were SQL, it would be rather easy.  Just:

```
 DECLARE AmountPaid int = (SELECT SUM(AmountPaid) FROM table WHERE tenantname = @TenantName)
 DECLARE Rent int = (SELECT SUM(MonthlyRent) FROM table WHERE tenantname = @TenantName)

 RETURN MonthlyRent - AmountPaid
```

In any case, I am looking to do this in Excel sans macros and sans VB.  Inline is preferred, but I am prepared for the answer to this to be "can't be done like that".

Comment: So basically you want I3 = C3 - F3 + G3 + I2, but instead of I2 you need to look up the last I value for that same Tenant?

Comment: You can add another column that does a `sumif` on column A and I?

Comment: C8H10N4O2:  Yes.  That is exactly what I am looking for.

Comment: findwindow:  What would that look like, exactly?  I'm not sure how the sumif() would help here, but am open to the idea.

Comment: In your example you are charging them twice for November rent. Wouldn't the desired ending balance be $75.00

Comment: @ScottCraner yea, I was a bit confused first but the rent due date and late fee suggest that tenant is making multiple payments. (That's how I took it but yea, could be better presented.) Edit: lol I just noticed that discrepancy to my logic XD

Comment: The amount paid being less than the rent due is also an indication that the tenant is making multiple payments.  Not to mention that in my question I specifically call out that the tenant is making partial payments.  The Monthly rent doesn't really change.  For all I care, it could come from a VLOOKUP.  In any case, it is really a static value.  Yes @ScottCraner, the desired value would be 75 for balance due.  Keep in mind that I will have other tenants who also may make partial payments each month

Comment: No @ScottCraner saying that my `sumif` doesn't work. I am bad at math :/

Comment: Outside of pivot tables which will take some work, the only way is with a User Defined Function.  Or you can do this a way an accountant would, one sheet for each tenant with a new line for each transaction whether credit or debit, keeping a running total that can be passed back to a main sheet or account.

Comment: Scott's saying basically, you shouldn't list rent (column C) twice for same month. Edit: or his last comment on double entry accounting works too (better).

Comment: @ScottCraner, I see what you are saying, but that creates a problem that is no different a problem than the one I have before me right now.  I can set C2 to be the balance from I1, but then I am right back where I started.  That works for Tenant #1 and as long as I don't enter anyone else's rent in this log, that works.  The minute I do this for tenant #2...Tenant #N, that fails.

Comment: That is why you need to have each tenant on their own individual sheet and on the main sheet you will only have one line per tenant showing the balance which is linked to a cell on the tenants page.  Proper accounting practice is one line per transaction, you are trying to put three or four a line.  Even with a UDF, this will be hard to do.  Excel cannot guess whether to include a number or not.

Comment: But....I like having 3 or 4 transactions....  :(  Like I said, I was prepared for "no, you cant do it".  Your approach to 1 tenant per sheet was the original option and I didn't like it.  Thought I'd ask.  Thanks guys.

Comment: After all that  I was driving to an appointment andfigured out how to do it I am on my phone and will get back to you when I can get back to my computer. Unless someone else can answer first.

Comment: Am waiting with baited breath.  But heading home.  Will check in later.  TY again!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Three options for you.

**First Option**

This requires that the rent be put in only once per month no matter how many transaction per month.  Put the following formula in I2 and copy down:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$C$1:$C2)-SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$F$1:$F2)+SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$G$1:$G2)-SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$H$1:$H2)
```

[image]

**Second Option**

If you want to have the reference of the monthly rent on every line you will need a helper column.  As I stated in the comments, Excel can not guess whether to use a number or not.  So add column between C and D for a Y or N.  The formula would then be:

```
=SUMIFS($C$1:$C2,$A$1:$A2,A2,$D$1:$D2,"Y")-SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$G$1:$G2)+SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$H$1:$H2)-SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$I$1:$I2)
```

[image]

**Third Option** *My Choice*

One last argument for one line per transaction.

Rent is due on the first no matter when the rent is paid and so on the first the balance should reflect that.  Late fees have a specific date that it is accrued regardless of date of payment and should be added to the balance as of that date.

With the sumif formulas above we can keep it all on one sheet.  The formula would be:

```
=SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$E$1:$E2)-SUMIF($A$1:$A2,A2,$D$1:$D2)
```

[image]

Comment: I am certainly going to give this a shot!  I think I will choose door #3 Monty!!  Will approve your answer once I confirm on my end, but from the looks of it, I am pretty sure this will work for me!  Thanks!

Comment: One follow-up question for door 3.  What I would like, ideally, is for the original rent amount to be "known" by excel.  IOW, I enter Tenant 1 in A, Excel looks up tenant 1 and finds his rent to be 500.  Any remaining entries for that month for that tenant increase or decrease the balance due.  Is there a way to pull that off?

Comment: @DJ The best way would be to create an event procedure on the cell changes that automatically puts in the rent value in the correct box, but that's vba.  With formulas, you will need to add a column between A and B.  Use a vlookup equation in the new column that looks at column A and compares it to a list somewhere else that has all the tenants and their monthly rent.  It cannot be in the balance equation, because if rent changes the vlookups are still live and will change the old numbers throwing off the balance.

Comment: I am trying your approach and I have to admit, I really like it a lot.  I am going to approve your answer.  You have been very helpful.  1 last question.  I can settle for entering the rent monthly, manually, but would like the late fee calculated based on the monthly rent.  I think I have a way do do this, but would appreciate how you might approach that.  My thoughts are to use a vlookup table for rent and late fee rate calculated only when date is greater than 1st of month + 6

Comment: I figured out how to automate the late fee by pretty much following your advice for rent.  It makes sense to enter the rent 1 time per month.  This was exactly what I wanted.  Thanks again!

Comment: @DJ Glad I could help.

Comment: @findwindow did you ever see how I made this work?  After all my bluster and ranting I figured it out.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest a PivotTable - of your first seven columns (A for ROWS, C, F and G for Sum of VALUES) and a Calculated Field of Sum of say BALANCE, being:

```
=C + G - F
```

the details might then be extracted by drilling down to suit.